# How to Install and run iniparser for Eclipse CDT?

Tags: c, eclipse-cdt, configuration-files, ini

I have been trying to find a way to install the [iniparser library](https://github.com/ndevilla/iniparser) to write configuration files for C  programs in eclipse, the whole day today. But I have not been able to find anything usefull. I am using Windows 7 (64 bit).

I have tried downloading the zip file and loading it into the 'lib' folders of eclipse. But when I try to include it into the C program it gives me a error saying 'iniparser.h' not found.

Can somebody PLEASE tell me how can I do this?? I would really be thankfull..

Answer (score 0):

You can include path-

Try-

```
Project -> properties -> C/C++General -> Paths and Symbols -> Includes tab -> Assembly
```

while checking 'add to all languages'.

This  one did not work for me- `Project -> Properties -> C/C++General -> Paths and Symbols -> Includes tab -> GCC C`